# My Firefox extension won't install

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm just got everything set up in my Firefox extension. Now I need to install it into live Firefox, and I'm having trouble. I got the .xpi file made, with my manifest inside. Everything seems to be going fine, and I even get this screen:

[image]

But after I click install and restart Firefox, nothing is installed.

Here is the install.rdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
  <em:id>canoncheck@canoncheck.com</em:id>
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>

<!-- Target Application this extension can install into,
         with minimum and maximum supported versions. -->

<em:targetApplication>
    <Description>
      <!-- Firefox's UUID -->
      <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
      <em:minVersion>3.0.*</em:minVersion>
      <em:maxVersion>34.0.*</em:maxVersion>
    </Description>
  </em:targetApplication>

  <!-- Front End MetaData -->
  <!-- Extension Information -->
  <em:name>Canon Check</em:name>
  <em:description>Check for canonical links in the loaded page.</em:description>
  <em:creator>Jase Pellerin</em:creator>

  <!-- Front End Integration Hooks (used by Theme Manager)-->
    <em:internalName>canoncheck</em:internalName>
  </Description>

</RDF>
```

Any ideas what's messing it up? I think it's the above. I'm gonna make a new one using the template here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility

Comment: doesn't ur addon shows in about:addons page ? if your addon doesn't support your firefox version ,firefox will give you a error and will not install the addon

Comment: It doesn't show up in about:addons :c There doesn't seem to be an error either. I install, it restarts, and then it's not there!

Comment: ok did you run it using `cfx run` ?? then you will see the problem in output console

Comment: Yeah, it runs fine in cfx. Maybe it has to do with install.rdf?

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors in the initiation code, mains.js?

Comment: Ahh, I didn't even know you could do that! There is one message that says "You must have called check() before sending."